# reveal.js produces blank page

Tags: html, css, reveal.js

I'm having some problems with getting reveal.js to work. Since the [instructions](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#instructions) don't really say where to put the files or what to name them (is that obvious?), I'm having problems even getting the example code on the instruction page to work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/white.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>Slide 1</section>
                <section>Slide 2</section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/reveal.js"></script>
        <script>
            Reveal.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've put this code into a file called `test.html`, and copies the `css` folder in the `reveal.js` repository into the same folder as `test.html`.

When I open `test.html` in Firefox or IE, I just get a completely white web page without anything on it, and nothing happens when I press the arrow keys. If I change `"css/theme/white.css"` to some other theme, I manage to change the background color of the page but I still don't get any content on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that except from referring to files in the `css` folder, the code also refers to a file in the `js` folder. Therefore, I also needed to copy the `js` folder in the `reveal.js` repository into the same folder as `test.html`.

Alternatively, I can change the references, so that I instead have

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<path-to-reveal.js>/css/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<path-to-reveal.js>/css/theme/white.css">
```

and

```
        <script src="<path-to-reveal.js>/js/reveal.js"></script>
```

in `test.html`.